# Importing same .less file in every angular component template?

Tags: angular, less

In my angular cli project I have:

**angular-cli.json:**

`"styles": [
        "styles/styles.less"
      ],`

**styles.less:**

```
@import 'general';
```

**general.less:**

```
.pointer {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

In **component's styles .less** I use a mixin:

```
.homeblocks .block{
    .pointer;
}
```

I have to do an import in each **template's less** file (couldn't find another way):

`@import '../../styles/general.less';`

If I don't import it, i get an error: `.pointer is undefined`

- Now, if I want to use global variables or mixins defined in a less
  file, do i have to import it in every component?
- Will this create duplication of styles in every component?

Comment: I don't know about LESS, but SASS has `placeholders` that I think address the issue you are talking about. Instead of defining the reusable style that you import in multiple places as a class, you define it as a placeholder. Placeholders will not get translated into CSS unless you "use" them. [Here is a post about mixins vs extend vs placeholders](http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/SASS-mixins-extends-and-placeholders-differences-use-cases). Maybe LESS has something equivalent?

Comment: I found [this open issue](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1177#issuecomment-18365365) on the LESS repo about "placeholder" support.

Comment: Have you tryied to use <link rel="stylesheet" href=general"... in app.component.html ?

Comment: Looking at the bundle.css after `ng build --prod` I see only one instance of the .pointer class, I guess less compiler is smart enough and doesn't create duplicate styles for each component.

Answer (score 4):

Rembember that `mixins` and `variables` only exist on `css processor` level (in your case on the `less` level). They are then processed to `css`. Having this it means anything that needs to be resolved during compile time it needs to be imported on every file that needs to use it. The final stylesheet is only built and composed during the processing of all the `css processor` files. When you have them in partials they have no idea of what’s already declared or not.

Regarding the duplicate styles I’m afraid that’s one of the drawbacks of having style encapsulation. Which also means you need to be careful to what you `import` inside each component stylesheet. Every instance of the component will have the exact same imports and styles. It can escalate really bad if for instance you `import bootstrap` inside a widely used component.  Ideally the components stylesheets should only have small very specific amounts of styles.

One way you have to avoid this is not using the encapsulation by avoiding the use of the `styleUrls` and compose your stylesheets the old way. Letting `less` do what was designed for

Comment: *Regarding the duplicate styles* - one at leaast should (actually *must*) use normal parametric mixins instead of regular rulesets (e.g. `.pointer {...}` shoud be `.pointer() {...}`). This at least won't place unused `.pointer` into every component CSS (while the "mixed-in" properties remain duplicated of course).